# Error retrieving information from server RPC:S-7 AEC-0

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implemented Google in app billing to my Application. I created SKU product id and implemented the billing process in code. While I am trying to test for one account details it worked fine for me but when am testing with some other accoutnt enter all the test account details, location, phone no etc and clicking save button it gives the error "Error retrieving information from server RPC S-7 AEC-0". I too published the app created the test account and signed in to the device with test account.

Comment: I am also looking for the solution for this error.